# Using MinGW to compile C code, but error liblto_plugin-0.dll not found?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, mingw, mingw32

I'm using MinGW to compile C code. but when I give command "make", appear error :  gcc.exe : fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin-0.dll not found compilation terminated. make: *** [all] Error 1. Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: It means that you need `liblto_plugin-0.dll` installed correctly on system to do the compilation. Check out this: http://old.nabble.com/liblto_plugin-0.dll-not-found-td31552675.html maybe help you

Comment: FYI, `liblto_plugin-0.dll` installed in C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.7.0 . Sorry, I didn't find any information to solve my problem in your link you give to me.. :-)

Answer (score 3):

though a long time since asked, I faced the same issue and I found a fine workaround when compiling.

`gcc -fno-use-linker-plugin test.cpp -o test`

Comment: This is the sign of a bad toolchain build though.

Comment: This answer saved me hours. Could you explain why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Check your PATH environment variable and look for a path to another MinGW installation. I have two MinGW installed (first one in Falcon C++ IDE directory), and second one I installed by myself. There was two paths to MinGW in system PATH environment variable and that induced the error.